# What is the most efficient way to create a DB record in Django 2.0 without knowing if it already exists?

Tags: django, django-models

The situation is that a DB must be populated but it is unknown whether the records already exist or not. The primary key is an incremented value. **I consider three techniques to accomplish this task but wonder which is the most efficient.**

1.

```
Model.objects.get_or_create()
```

2.

```
Model.objects.update_or_create()
```

3.

```
if not Model.objects.filter().exists():
    Model.objects.create()
```

According to the Django docs, techniques 1 and 2 internally use EAFP (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission), while Technique 3 uses the less favored LBYL (Look before you leap). However, technique 3 avoids retrieving or saving (without modification) the object if it already exists. Is the assignment costly enough to desire avoiding or does the lookup cost outweigh the rest of the actions?

**Follow up: Does the correct method change in the cases where there are a majority of already existing records vs a majority of non-existing records?**

Comment: Is it intentional not to use a bulk insert?

Comment: @spectras From what I have read, bulk_create will either create duplicate records without integrity constraints or fail as a whole on any one violation.

Comment: Sure, but if using bulk_create is acceptable, you could use approach 3, one large select then a bulk_create. If bulk_create is not acceptable, this rules out that option.

Comment: It depends on your use case. Use 1 or 2 whenever possible but in some places (such as overriding the `save()` method of a model) it might be necessary to use 3 or your own implementation of EAFP (also known as `try`/`except`). See https://github.com/django/django/blob/6ae7aaa7d6eb880043c4c80009b36e2287bfcb92/django/db/models/query.py#L490 for the actual implementation.